# Unable to see markers added before on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing this app where user gathers on same activity and in that activity there is a `Map` which gets updated as soon as a user is added and shows his/her location on the map. I have a list in which users who opens this activity gets added and I'm using its adapter's `getAdapterItemCount()` property to implement my logic.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
                mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapLoaded() {
                        //animate camera here

                        if (aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() > 0 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() == 1 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() < 2) {
     pMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pWhoAccepted.trim()));
     markersList.add(pMarker);
} else if (aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() > 1 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() == 2 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() < 3) {
     sPlayerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pWhoAccepted.trim()));
     markersList.add(sPlayerMarker);
} else if (aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() > 2 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() == 3 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() < 4) {
     tPlayerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pWhoAccepted.trim()));
     markersList.add(tPlayerMarker);
} else if (aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() > 3 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() == 4 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() < 5) {
     fPlayerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pWhoAccepted.trim()));
     markersList.add(fPlayerMarker);
} else if (aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() > 4 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() == 5 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() < 6) {
     faPlayerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pWhoAccepted.trim()));
     markersList.add(faPlayerMarker);
} else if (aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() > 5 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() == 6 && aFastItemAdapter.getAdapterItemCount() < 7) {
     saPlayerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLtAU, currentLnAU)).title(pWhoAccepted.trim()));
     markersList.add(saPlayerMarker);
}

                        ////get the latLngbuilder from the marker list
                        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                        for (Marker m : markersList) {
                            builder.include(m.getPosition());
                        }

                        //Bounds padding here
                        int padding = 100;

                        //Create bounds here
                        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                        //Create camera with bounds
                        final CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

                        mMap.animateCamera(cu);

                        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(19.0f);

                    }
                });
```

**The problem is** that suppose there is already a `marker` on the map and I'm the second one to get added so the user who was added before me can see my marker on the map but, I am unable to see his.

What is wrong with my code and **How can I** let every user see all the markers available on the map regardless of the fact they are added in first or whatever position?